# NSubstitute Mocking Class or Interface?

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I have an interface IFileWriter as below:

```
public interface IFileWriter
{
  void WriteFile();
}
```

The class implementation is as below:

```
public class MyClass : IFileWriter
{ 
  private readonly ILogger<...> _logger;

  public MyClass(ILogger<...> logger)
   {
     _logger = logger;
    }
 }
```

Now I am using XUnit to Mock MyClass as below:

```
public class MyClassTest
{
  private readonly ILogger<...> _logger;
  private readonly IFileWriter _writer;

    public MyClassTest()
    {
        _logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<...>>();
        _writer= new MyClass (_logger);
    }
 }
```

I am currently using the actual class, but mocking only the dependency. Is the above approach correct or should I be using the Interface of MyClass instead of new MyClass?

Comment: It depends what you are testing. If you are testing the implementation of `MyClass` you will need an actual `MyClass` instance. If `IFileWriter` is a dependency for the class you are testing then it can be mocked.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thank you - so in theory - it means that we only mock dependencies and not the actually service class that we are testing. Have I got this right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.